Alter table - add a new column as the first column in the table - sql server
Before doing a restore of a database I check how much space I have in each drive on the destination server.
I use this script:

IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#FREE_SPACE_DRIVES','u') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #FREE_SPACE_DRIVES;
END


CREATE TABLE #FREE_SPACE_DRIVES(
DRIVE CHAR(1)PRIMARY KEY,
FREESPACE BIGINT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #FREE_SPACE_DRIVES
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_fixeddrives;


then to see what are the available disk space I use the following query:
select d.DRIVE  
      ,[DriveFreeSpace(GB)] =   REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CAST(    CAST(d.FREESPACE/1024.00 as DECIMAL(12,2))     AS MONEY),1), '.00','')
from  #FREE_SPACE_DRIVES D with(nolock)

and that gives me:

that is all good, but now I want the servername shown on the picture as well.
ok I can add @@servername to my script and it will show the servername too.
select [Server Name] = 'DBA Paradise' --@@servername 
      ,d.DRIVE  
      ,[DriveFreeSpace(GB)] =   REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CAST(    CAST(d.FREESPACE/1024.00 as DECIMAL(12,2))     AS MONEY),1), '.00','')
from  #FREE_SPACE_DRIVES D with(nolock)


My question is actually about alter table.
when I do this alter table:
ALTER TABLE #FREE_SPACE_DRIVES
add  server_name nvarchar(128) not null default (@@servername)

when I run this select:
select * from  #FREE_SPACE_DRIVES


I get:

that is all good, but I need the new column to be the first in my table,
is there a way to get this done?
then the result would be

server_name, drive, freespace



that is all good, but I need the new column to be the first in my table, is there a way to get this done?

SELECT server_name, DRIVE, FREESPACE

You shouldn't care what the ordinal number of a column in metadata is in the database. Select the columns in the order you want.

Agreed with Sean...
But in the interest of answering the question for those who have a use case where column ordinal matters, one way to accomplish your goal is by selecting everything into a new table with the new column defined in the proper column order. Then renaming the table after, like so:
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), '') AS server_name, *
INTO #SomeNewTable
FROM #FREE_SPACE_DRIVES;

DROP TABLE #FREE_SPACE_DRIVES;

SELECT *
INTO #FREE_SPACE_DRIVES
FROM #SomeNewTable;

DROP TABLE #SomeNewTable;

If this was a non-temp table, you'd be able to actually call sp_rename instead of having to do a double INSERT like so:
EXEC sp_rename N'SomeNewTable', N'FREE_SPACE_DRIVES';

But no biggie either way.

I also agree with Sean, but if your actual script is what you have shown, then I would do it in this way.
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#FREE_SPACE_DRIVES','u') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #FREE_SPACE_DRIVES;
END

/** ADD your new column in the correct ordinal position to start with. **/
CREATE TABLE #FREE_SPACE_DRIVES(
    [Server Name] NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT(@@SERVERNAME),
    DRIVE CHAR(1)PRIMARY KEY,
    FREESPACE BIGINT NOT NULL
)

/** SPECIFY the columns that the stored procedure is going to insert into **/
INSERT INTO #FREE_SPACE_DRIVES
    (DRIVE, FREESPACE)
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_fixeddrives;

/** SPECIFY the desired order of the output **/
SELECT [Server Name], DRIVE, FREESPACE 
FROM #FREE_SPACE_DRIVES

/** ALTERNATIVE, Just do this... **/
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS [Server Name]
    , DRIVE 
    , FREESPACE 
FROM #FREE_SPACE_DRIVES

